# Is there simple way to play an rtp video/audio stream in WPF?

Tags: wpf, streaming, rtp

I need to create a WPF control that will play an rtp stream with the requirement that the latency needs to be as low as possible.

I've looked at the following two projects:

http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/
http://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/

As far as I know, I can't use VLC because we're shipping a commercial application with a more restrictive license than GPL (i.e. we can't ship our source).

Wpf media kit is nice, but I can't seem to find a good/free rtp directshow source filter and I wanted to ask if there is a simpler solution out there that I'm missing before I jump into writing my own.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VLC uses the [LIVE555](http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/) library for the RTP/RTSP side of things so perhaps that will be useful to you, it's licensed under LGPL. It is a C++ library so you'd have to get out pinvoke and since I haven't ever used the library I can't say how difficult that would be.

There is [pjsip.net](http://sites.google.com/site/sipekphone/pjsipwrapper) but looks like it's [GPL](http://www.pjsip.org/licensing.htm) since that's what the underlying [pjsip](http://pjsip.org) and [pjmedia](http://www.pjsip.org/pjmedia/docs/html/index.htm) are.

Here's a handy list of [RTP stacks](http://www.pernau.at/kd/voip/bookmarks-rtp-stacks.html).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I was hoping that there was some magical solution out there that google just couldn't find, but we all know that's rarely the case. Looks like I'll be making my own.

Answer (score 3):

There's not *simple* solution that I've come across.  I have made RTSP filter's in the past using LIVE555, but I don't think that falls into the realm of "easy".

I did see [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rtspdirectshow/) on source forge, but I read comments questioning if it even works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried out that source forge project and after messing around to get it to compile, I got a protected memory read/write exception, so I guess I can confirm that it doesn't actually work out of the box.